# Have a JScrollPane scroll all the way to the bottom BUT always at the left, not the end

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jscrollpane, jtextarea

My JScrollPane is able to scroll to the bottom every time when text is appended to the JTextArea using the following code:

```
DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret) textArea.getCaret();
caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
```

However, if the text is too long and does not fit in the viewable part of the box, it scrolls to the right (literal end of the text area).

Is there any way to perhaps ignore the horizontal change in text and just scroll vertically automatically (keeping the current horizontal columns being viewed). Either this, or always have it to the left side.

Comment: you may disable Horizontal Scrolling, 
`JScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);`

Comment: What if you still want to be able to scroll horizontally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have something like an `append(String)` method, which allows you to easily append things to your `JTextArea`, then you could also update that area with something like the following:

```
public void append(String s) {
    area.append(s.endsWith("\n") ? s : s + "\n"); // your choice here
    area.setCaretPosition(Math.max(area.getText().lastIndexOf("\n"), 0)); // update pos
}
```

Which would put the caret at the last `\n` in the text.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to manually adjust the viewport position. So you can create an append(...) method with code something like:

```
public void append(JTextArea textArea, String text)
{
    textArea.append( text );

    Component parent = textArea.getParent();

    if (parent instanceof JViewport)
    {
        JViewport viewport = (JViewport)parent;
        Point p = viewport.getViewPosition();

        if (p.x != 0)
        {
            p.x = 0;
            viewport.setViewPosition( p );
        }
    }
}
```

Or instead of changing the view position you can reset the Caret to the start of the line which should cause the viewport to reset to the left automatically:

```
textArea.append( text );
textArea.setCaretPosition( Utilities.getRowStart(textArea, textArea.getCaretPosition() );
```